# New Mac Application - which certificate for the Accessibility API with Sandboxing?

Tags: cocoa, code-signing

I´ve been working on a mac app and now I would like to submit this app to the Mac App Store.

I have to code sign my app and I have three certificates:

1. a Mac Application Development Signing Certificate (named "Mac Developer + my name")
2. a Mac Application Distribution Signing Certificate (named "3rd Party Mac Developer Application + my name")
3. and a Mac Installer Package Distribution Signing Certificate (named "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer + my name")

Which one do I have to use to code sign my app to submit to the MAS? I think is the second one but I not sure.

Thanks in advance.